# How to split single file in to multiple pieces using php?

Tags: php, web, web-applications, backend

I'm looking for a code to split single file in to multiple files just like torrent.

I'm going to try this as a web application. So I need a code for back-end

When user input a file of 200mb ; the output must split the file in to smaller pieces like 20kb/file

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please show some attempt so people will be eager to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There you go...

```
// 20 KB
$partSize = 20 * 1024;
$fileSize = filesize($theFile);

$fileNameTemplate = __DIR__ . '/split_no_%04d.whatever';
$fileHandle = fopen($theFile, 'r');
$counter = 0;
while($fileSize > 0 && !feof($fileHandle)) {
    $counter++;
    // create a new filename
    $newFile = sprintf($fileNameTemplate, $counter);
    // open new file
    $writeHandle = fopen($newFile, 'w');
    // read portion of the big file
    $content = fread($fileHandle, $partSize);
    // write it to the new file
    $written = fwrite($writeHandle, $content);
    // close file pointer
    fclose($writeHandle);
    // adjust remaining bytes
    $fileSize -= $written;

    echo '- '. $written . ' bytes'. PHP_EOL;
}
```